# How to display only filename selected in pysimplegui when using a text label in front

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

It's my first try at a pysimplegui application.
Before I was using tkinter a lot but interface doesn't look that pretty and modern looking.

What I want to do is to have a window with 3 button, 2 to select different files and one to launch comparison function.
After selecting the file I just want to interface to display the filename.
If I add a sg.Text() it displays the full filepath which I don't want to because I only need to display the filename to the user.

Here is the minimal code to reproduce what I experience :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

# layout = [
#     [sg.InputText(size=(45, 1), key="File_1", disabled=True), sg.FileBrowse(enable_events=True, key="File_path_1", target=(0, 1))],
#     [sg.InputText(size=(45, 1), key="File_2", disabled=True), sg.FileBrowse(enable_events=True, key="File_path_2", target=(1, 1))],
#     [sg.Submit()]
#         ]

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Old_file '), sg.InputText(size=(45, 1), key="File_1", disabled=True), sg.FileBrowse(enable_events=True, key="File_path_1", target=(0, 1))],
    [sg.Text('New_file'), sg.InputText(size=(45, 1), key="File_2", disabled=True), sg.FileBrowse(enable_events=True, key="File_path_2", target=(1, 1))],
    [sg.Submit()]
        ]
window = sg.Window("File compare", layout)


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None or event == "Cancel":
        break
    elif event == "File_path_1":
        filepath = values.get('File_path_1')
        window['File_1'].update(os.path.basename(filepath))
    elif event == "File_path_2":
        filepath = values.get('File_path_2')
        window['File_2'].update(os.path.basename(filepath))
    elif event == 'Submit':
        print("hello")
```

Here is the picture of what I get with text-label in front of it in layout :
[image]

My question is how to make it only display the filename even with the text-label in front of the filename text cell.
When I add a sg.Text() element before the sg.InputText() it shows the filepath instead of the filename like I wanted initially.
I thought that the key would allow to update only some part of the UI but it doesn't work that way when a sg.Text() elem is before the InputText that I want to update with the filename and NOT the filepath.

Edit : I used PySimpleGUI-4-foss==4.60.4.1 package instead of PysimpleGUI v5.0.3
Thanks Mimo for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really sorry for the issue not sure why first time it worked. this is an updated version.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Old_file '), sg.Input(size=(45, 1), key="File_1", readonly=True), sg.FileBrowse(target='Hidden_Browse_1', key='Browse_1', enable_events=True), sg.In(visible=False, enable_events=True, key='Hidden_Browse_1')],
    [sg.Text('New_file'), sg.Input(size=(45, 1), key="File_2", readonly=True), sg.FileBrowse(target='Hidden_Browse_2', key='Browse_2', enable_events=True), sg.In(visible=False, enable_events=True, key='Hidden_Browse_2')],
    [sg.Submit()]
]

window = sg.Window("File compare", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None or event == "Cancel":
        break
    elif event == "Hidden_Browse_1":
        filepath = values.get('Hidden_Browse_1')
        window['File_1'].update(os.path.basename(filepath))
    elif event == "Hidden_Browse_2":
        filepath = values.get('Hidden_Browse_2')
        window['File_2'].update(os.path.basename(filepath))
    elif event == 'Submit':
        print("hello")
```

I apologize for the confusion. The `sg.popup_get_file()` function opens a file dialog, which is why you're seeing two file dialogs when you click the Browse button.

To fix this, you can use the `sg.FileBrowse` button with the `target` parameter set to a hidden `sg.Input` field. Then, in your event loop, you can update the visible `sg.Input` field with the filename.

Here's how you can do it:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import os

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Old_file '), sg.Input(size=(45, 1), key="File_1", readonly=True), sg.FileBrowse(target='Hidden_Browse_1', key='Browse_1', enable_events=True), sg.In(visible=False, enable_events=True, key='Hidden_Browse_1')],
    [sg.Text('New_file'), sg.Input(size=(45, 1), key="File_2", readonly=True), sg.FileBrowse(target='Hidden_Browse_2', key='Browse_2', enable_events=True), sg.In(visible=False, enable_events=True, key='Hidden_Browse_2')],
    [sg.Submit()]
]

window = sg.Window("File compare", layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None or event == "Cancel":
        break
    elif event == "Hidden_Browse_1":
        filepath = values.get('Hidden_Browse_1')
        window['File_1'].update(os.path.basename(filepath))
    elif event == "Hidden_Browse_2":
        filepath = values.get('Hidden_Browse_2')
        window['File_2'].update(os.path.basename(filepath))
    elif event == 'Submit':
        print("hello")
```

the `sg.FileBrowse` buttons target hidden `sg.Input` fields. When a file is selected, the hidden `sg.Input` field is updated with the full file path and an event is triggered. Then, in your event loop, you can retrieve the file path from the hidden `sg.Input` field, get the filename using `os.path.basename()`, and update the visible `sg.Input` field with the filename.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I wanted. So I guess my original key "Browse_1" and "Browse_2" are not needed anymore with that target solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None or event == "Cancel":
        break
    elif event == "File_path_1":
        filepath = values.get('File_path_1')
        window['File_1'].update(os.path.basename(filepath))
    elif event == "File_path_2":
        filepath = values.get('File_path_2')
        window['File_2'].update(os.path.basename(filepath))
    elif event == 'Submit':
        print("hello")
```

use the `os.path.basename()` instead of `split()` method as split return tuple.

Comment: Yes os.path.basename() is getting rid of {} but my initial question is why when I put old_file and new_file in front of the filename text display (it shows the filepath instead). That's why I have put 2 layout one is commented to show what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by

- use the function `popup_get_file` to get the filename
- the attribute `element.metadata` to keep the full path of the file
- function `os.path.basename` to get the base filename.

```py
import os
import PySimpleGUI as sg

font = ("Courier New", 12)
sg.set_options(font=font)

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Old File"), sg.Input(disabled=True, key="OLD", metadata=""), sg.Button("Browse", key="Browse OLD")],
    [sg.Text("New File"), sg.Input(disabled=True, key="NEW", metadata=""), sg.Button("Browse", key="Browse NEW")],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Push()],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if event.startswith("Browse"):
        _, key = event.split(" ")
        full_path = sg.popup_get_file("Filename", no_window=True)
        if full_path:
            window[key].metadata = full_path
            window[key].update(os.path.basename(full_path))

window.close()
```